# Regex that allows only one space in the first/last name validation

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm trying to write a regular expression to remove white spaces from just the beginning of the word, not after, and only a single space after the word.

Used RegExp:

```
var re = new RegExp(/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\s?)*$/);
```

Test Exapmle:

```
1) test[space]ing - Should be allowed 
2) testing - Should be allowed 
3) [space]testing - Should be allowed but have to trim the space at the first
4) testing[space] - Should be allowed but have to trim the space at the last 
5) testing[space][space] - should be allowed but have to trim the space at the last  
6) test[space][space]ing - one space should be allowed but the remaining spaces have to be trimmed.
```

Any idea how this can be achieved using regex?

**EDIT:**

I have this,

```
 var regExp = /^(\w+\s?)*\s*$/;
if(regExp.test($('#FirstName').val())){
                    $('#FirstName').val().replace(/\s+$/, '');
                }else{
                    var elm = $('#FirstName'),
                    msg = 'First Name must consist of letters with no spaces';
                    return false;
                }
```

Comment: What is the expected result for the last (6) string? `test[space]ing` or `false` ?

Comment: @falsetru `test[space]ing` is expected

Comment: Example does not contains not allowed case. Could you give the example that is not allowed at all?

Comment: @falsetru not allowed case is empty val for firstname

Answer (score 2):

Using capturing group:

```
var re = /^\s+|\s+$|(\s)\s+/g;
'test ing'.replace(re, '$1')   // => 'test ing'
'testing'.replace(re, '$1')    // => 'testing'
' testing'.replace(re, '$1')   // => 'testing'
'testing '.replace(re, '$1')   // => 'testing'
'testing  '.replace(re, '$1')  // => 'testing'
'test  ing'.replace(re, '$1')  // => 'test ing'
```

Comment: @coderman, If it is not allowed, `var name = $('#FirstName').val().replace(re, '$1'); if (name) { ... } else { ... return false; }` seems enough.

Comment: only two possible inputs are allowed say `testing` and `test ing` and rest other spaces have to be trimmed.

Comment: @coderman, In the answer, spaces are trimed as you comment as you commented, aren't they?

Comment: `te st ing` has to accept since it has only one space in between.

Comment: @coderman, `'te st ing'.replace(re, '$1')` returns `"te st ing"`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably be lazy to keep it simple and use two separate REs:

```
// Collapse any multiple spaces into one - handles cases 5 & 6
str.replace(/ {2,}/, ' ');

// Trim any leading space
str.replace(/^ /, '');
```

Or, as one statement:

```
var result = str.replace(/ {2,}/, ' ').replace(/^ ?/, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
replace(/^ | $|( ) +/, $1)?
```